# Hypothesis test for significance of linear fit?

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals

I've used [scipy.odr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) to fit lines through each of the four scatter plots below. The function's [Output](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Output.html) includes the `res_var` attribute: the residual variance, which I've shown on each of the four panels.

The fits look noisier for panels (b) and (d) than for (a) and (c). I am looking for some kind of significance test that will reject (b) and (d) and accept (a) and (c). I cannot go directly with the `res_var` values because it is influenced by the absolute values of points; e.g. panel (c) for which I have increased the variance. I guess I could normalise `res_var` but I'm not sure how, and how can I turn this into some kind of hypothesis test to reject/accept?

[image]